# Are there any German-language films for streaming on Netflix?

Tags: resource, online-resource

I've discovered a lot of German-language films on Netflix that are available on DVD. But I haven't found any that are available for streaming. Are there any German-language films on Netflix available for streaming? Kind of like how Amelie is available for streaming in French?

Comment: In which country?

Comment: In the United States.

Comment: The are German films on Netflix in Germany. However they might not be available in the US. Try "Das Boot", "Das Leben der Anderen", "Bang Boom Bang", "Maria, ihm schmeckt's nicht", "Kokowäh", "Türkisch für Anfänger".

Answer (score 3):

Yes. This link will show you streaming Netflix films that have a German audio option: https://www.netflix.com/browse/audio/de

You just have to log in. You can also select other languages if you're interested, but this link goes directly to the German list.

Comment: Ah, yes. But there is one hitch. These movies have German audio, but I'm not sure how many of them are culturally German. I'm mainly looking for a German film that is set in Germany.

Comment: That's a different question than the one posed in the OP, though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a Netflix lookalike for German movies.
You can watch German productions on the websites of some TV channels though.

As far as I know, you can watch the more recent episodes or movies there.

You might try ARD or ZDF: on their websites, look for "Mediathek" or "Sendung verpasst".

Comment: ARD and ZDF Mediatheks most probably are not available from outside Germany.

Comment: @Eller You may be right. I didn’t think about that. Can anyone from a different country confirm this?